# Share firebase auth with embedded Flutter module

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, flutter-plugin

I have native iOS app with firebase auth and I also embedded flutter module in it (following this instructions https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup and CocoaPods)

I want to use firebase inside Flutter module as well as inside native part. How should I solve it?

One way is to add all necessary firebase libraries in Flutter module. In this case I will get 2 problems

1. code duplication
2. I still don’t know how to share firebase auth between app and module

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sharing firebase auth between app and module? What actions do you want to perform on the native side, and what actions do you want to perform on the Flutter side?

Comment: for example, once user is authorized in native app - he is also authorized in flutter part

Answer (score 2):

I can't guarantee this as I haven't tried it myself, but you shouldn't have any issues adding the dependencies to both Flutter and the native code.

1. The Flutter Firebase package depends on the native Firebase package, so you might think that the same package is imported twice resulting in code bloat, but that's not usually the case. Build tools are responsible for analyzing dependency trees and sorting that out. That being said, you might want to make sure that you use the same library version for both Flutter and the native side.
2. There is a stream in the Flutter Firebase Auth package that you might be able to use for keeping it in sync with the native side: `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged`. Unless you have customized the instantiation of the `FirebaseApp` used by Firebase Auth, then both Flutter and the native side actually point to the same instance of native `FirebaseApp`, so if you eg. log in on native, using either the stream I mentioned above or `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` should reveal the logged in user in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

As far as how I can see it, you should be able to help yourself using [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Based on our experience dealing with embedded Flutter views, we pass the authentication tokens via platform channels by using the `MethodChannel`.

Given that you are using Flutter's Add-to-App, I'm assuming that what you have is already a working app in native code before. In that case, you should be able to authenticate the user using Firebase Auth for the Android and iOS side, **separately**.

For example:

Assuming that you are using Kotlin, here's how you pass the token to Dart after authenticating the user using Android code.

**firebase_login.kt**

```
// Method to authenticate your user in Android
fun firebaseLogin() {
    ... 
    // Some callbacks from the Android side
    this.authenticateUserInFlutter("someTokenFromFirebase")
}

// @param token Can also be in a form of JSON object
func authenticateUserInFlutter(token: String) {
    val methodName = "authenticateUser"
    channel.invokeMethod(methodName, token, object: MethodChannel.Result {
        override fun success(result: Any?) {
            Log.i("MSG", "$result")
        }
        override fun error(code: String?, msg: String?, details: Any?) {
            Log.e("MSG", "$methodName failed: $msg")
        }
        override fun notImplemented() {
            Log.e("MSG", "$methodName not implemented")
        }
    })
}
```

And if you are using Swift for the iOS part.

**FirebaseLogin.swift**

```swift
func firebaseLogin() {
    ... 
    // Some callbacks from the iOS side
    self.authenticateUserInFlutter("someTokenFromFirebase")
}

fun authenticateUserInFlutter(token: String) {
    let methodName = "authenticateUser"
    channel.invokeMethod(methodName, arguments: value) {
    (result: Any?) -> Void in
        if let error = result as? FlutterError {
            os_log("%@ failed: %@", type: .error, methodName, error.message!)
        } else if FlutterMethodNotImplemented.isEqual(result) {
            os_log("%@ not implemented", type: .error, methodName)
        } else {
            os_log("%@", type: .info, result as! NSObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you should be able to capture the existing login tokens from the native side in your Dart code. You can use it to authenticate your user using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) for Flutter.

**my_platform_channels_handler.dart**

```dart
channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method) {
    case 'authenticateUser':
        val token = "${call.arguments}"; // You can also receive JSON arguments here

        // Start authenticating the user
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: token,
            idToken: ...,
        );
        final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;

        // Be able to reply to catch the errors here
        return null;
    case 'someMethodFromNative':
        print("someMethodFromNative method invoked from the native code!")
        return null;
    default:
        throw MissingPluginException();
    }
});
```

NOTE: You should be able to store and manage the tokens on both ends properly, native and Dart, so that the user experience will be seamless whenever your user is switching between the native views and the embedded Flutter views.

[image: diagram]

More on:

- https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth
- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
- https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e